# Https proxy server: обработка https запросов

Tags: ssl, proxy, https

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Разрабатываю прокси сервер и нужно как-то обрабатывать `https` запросы.
Когда я пытаюсь сделать запрос на хост с `https` то выдается ошибка связанная с ssl сертификатом (нужно регистрировать домен, но я хочу сделать локальную программу).
Есть ли какой нибудь путь через локальный `proxy` пропускать `https` запросы?

Comment: @Shidlovsky, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, какой язык используете и т. д.

Comment: Использую язык C#.
Создаю сокет, слушаю порт, получаю запрос.
Потом создаю еще один и отправляю его на реальный сервер.
Когда я читаю ответ с сервера от http запроса, у меня приходят все данные, а когда https, то у меня в ответе ничего нету

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS прокси должен обрабатывать запрос CONNECT и перенаправлять запрос на указанный адрес. SSL сертификаты в этом случае не требуются и не используются.

Полагаю у вас ошибка в логике программы, проверьте, что все работает правильно. Собственно, на прокси приходит запрос CONNECT от браузера, прокси подключается к указанному адресу и отвечает HTTP/1.1 200 OK в случае успешного подключения или выдает ошибку. Дальше браузер посылает HTTPS данные по тому же соединению, прокси пересылает их, получает ответ и возвращает его браузеру.

Answer (score 0):

Просто возьмите [готовое решение](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging)

А на сертификат будет ругаться - всё правильно, т.е. Вы НИКАК не сможете перешифровывать HTTPS-трафик прозрачно для конечного пользователя. Для этого Вы должны поставить ему свой корневой сертификат в браузер - это если оч коротко